# recursive scheme program to iterative

Tags: recursion, scheme, iteration

need help on making these two recursive programs in scheme iterative? 
I made the recursion, but am stuck at creating an iteration for both.

question 1 - recursion

```
(define mylength
 (lambda (l)
   (cond
   ((null? l) 0)
     (else (+ 1 (mylength (cdr l)))))))
```

question 1 - iteration?

question 2 - recursion

```
(define mylistref
  (lambda (l index)
   (cond
   ((= index 0)(car l))
     (else
       (mylistref (cdr l) (- index 1))))))
```

question 2 - iteration?

Comment: You probably mean recursive vs iterative process since Scheme only has recursion to do loops. Iterative calls itself in tail position thus the resutl fo the recursion is the result of the whote thing while recursive process needs to do something with the result. Thus in your first example it needs to add afterwards and thus recursive. Your second one is a iterative process since no work is done afterwards. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursion to iteration with proof?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253790/recursion-to-iteration-with-proof)

Answer (score 1):

Scheme does not have any looping structures so your only option is to use recursion if you are traversing over some kind of data structure.  [You can read more about it here](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Iteration.html)